# Are any of these bracket-fixing challenges duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[While collecting a list of all challenges related to balanced strings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8921/8478) I found that we have (at least) 4 challenges related to fixing unbalanced strings by adding or removing parentheses/braces/brackets. I haven't compared the specs in detail yet, but I figured there is likely going to be *some* overlap, and I thought it should probably be up to the community anyway to decide if any of those are duplicates or not:

- [Fix unbalanced brackets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11917/8478)
- [Finish lazy parentheses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25877/8478)
- [Write a program which replaces with spaces the braces in cases where braces in places cause stasis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36474/8478)
- [Fix the Braces, etc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50873/8478)

If the outcome is "they're all sufficiently different" that's fine, but I figured we should talk about it...

Comment: I believe that the #2 and #3 are sufficiently different from the others, but #4 and #1 are dupes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 and 4 are very similar. They both allow only brackets, and they both require the minimum number of additions to make the brackets fully balanced. 4 is newer, but IMO better written with a more concise spec. Therefore, we should close 1 as a dupe of 4.

2 and 3 are also very similar. Initially, I was going to recommend closing one of them, but I've changed my mind. I think the differences are significant enough that they should both stay open.

They both require parsing of string literals and comments, but 2:

- Is multiline.
- Only requires balancing parentheses.
- Allows adding or deleting of parentheses.

3:

- Is single line.
- Requires balancing several types of brackets.
- Only allows removing brackets.

So I'd say 2 and 3 should stay open.

Comment: I agree, so I went ahead and put the 5th dupe vote on 1.

Comment: @Mego \0/  \0/ !